# Rendering django template with a json object

Tags: django, json, templates

Consider a json object:
    {
      "config": {"key1": "value"}
    }

Within the html template (which is rendered using the above json as the context, how do access the "key1" directly? Conceptually I want to do the following:

```
<html>
<body>
The config value is {{config['key1']}}
</body>
</html>
```

but, obviously that does not work.

In other words how do I access any element of a dictionary object of the context within a template?

Comment: There is no such concept as JSON object in Python/Django. You need to use dictionary.

Comment: yup that is the right answer. I can not post it right now but would do that sometime soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue (as pointed out by Tomasz Zielinski in a comment)  that django supports dictionary objects directly - not json.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [dot notation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/templates/#variables):

```
<html>
    <body>
        The config value is {{ config.key1 }}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just saw that in the documents. I guess I need to use dictionaries instead of json objects in the template context values.